# Dynamically group poorly-structured HTML, that has no IDs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts

There is a very old website I use and the data is not displayed in a friendly fashion. I would like to write a userscript (javascript/jQuery) that assists the readability of this site. The content looks like (the HTML comments are my own, to help show this):

```
<font size="3" face="Courier">
  <br>
  <!-- Begin entry 1 -->
  Name1 (Location1) - Date1:
  <br>
  Text1
  <br>
  Text1 (continued)
  <br>
  Text1 (continued)
  <br>
  <br>
  <!-- Begin entry 2 -->
  Name2 (Location2) - Date2:
  <br>
  Text2
  <br>
  Text2 (continued)
  <br>
  <br>
  Text2 (continued)
  <br>
  Text2 (continued)
  <br>
  <br>
  <!-- Begin entry 3 -->
  Name3 (Location3) - Date3:
  <br>
  Text3
  <br>
  Text3 (continued)
  <br>
  Text3 (continued)
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  Text3 (continued)
  <br>
  Text3 (continued)
  <!-- Below is Text3, but a user copied Entry1 here --> 
  Name1 (Location1) - Date1: <!-- text3 -->
  <br> <!-- text3 -->
  Text1 <!-- text3 -->
  <br> <!-- text3 -->
  Text1 (continued) <!-- text3 -->
  <br> <!-- text3 -->
  Text1 (continued) <!-- text3 -->
  <br>
  <br>
  <!-- Begin entry 4 -->
  Name4 ...
  ......
</font>
```

- Example of names: `Bob Dole`, `SMITH,JOHN`
- Example of locations: `via Web`, `INTERNAL`
- Example of dates: `Jul 25, 2011 - 1317 EDT`, `Dec 30, 2011 - 1411 EST`
- Example of Text1/Text2/etc: `Blah blah * (test) text goes here -Thanks Here: there`

As you can see, two `<br>` always come before the next "entry" (name, location, date) but since the text is free text it can also contain various `<br>` including 2 or more. Another issue is if the text also contains `Name (Location) - Date` pasted from say another entry elsewhere.

So if I wanted to write a script that could be added to Google Chrome where it say added a button that would collapse (or uncollapse if already collapsed) each entry, is that possible? The issue I'm having is that since there is no unique element starting or ending an entry, I'm not sure how to begin this.

The general concept is to loop through each "entry" (header being name/location/date) and the text that follows that up until the next header) and allow each "entry" to be collapsible (such as Reddit comments are collapsible).

Or for a more simple concept, what if I wanted to mark every other entry with red font? So then all of entry1 would be black font, entry2 would be red font, entry3 would be black font, entry4 would be red font, and so on.

Comment: Just to clarify: I think there's a typo in your question. You have to br's right before saying "text 2" on line 19. Are there supposed to be to br's there?

Comment: @JBurace: document.getElementById is not the only way to get DOM elements, did you know that?

Comment: @SethAlexanderBird Yes, as clarified in the sentence below that: "Text1", "Text2", etc is all free text. So if someone pressed `enter`  when they wrote up this, it would come out with more `<br>`

Comment: You need to be more specific about your algorithm for finding what to hide.  Right now, it's not clear what the algorithm would be.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's what the question is about. I'm finding it difficult to come up with anything because there are no unique elements identifying where an entry begins and ends.

Comment: If you can't identify conceptually where an entry begins and ends you won't be able to do it programmatically.

Comment: @nnnnnn But there's a pattern to each entry (like two `<br>` followed by that name/location/date). It looks possible, I'm just finding it difficult to plan it out.

Comment: Show what a nested, or quoted, entry looks like.

Comment: How is a name different from any two words?  How is a location different from any set of words in parentheses?

Comment: @BrockAdams Just added that in, with comments.

Comment: Your name and location examples don't look any different from any other words.  As @nnnnnn said, if you can't identify a matching pattern that distinguishes from regular text, then a program can't do it either.  If there was an exclusive list of possible locations or an exclusive list of possible names, that would be one angle.  Otherwise, you're just limited to some text followed by some parenthesized text followed by something that looks like a date.  And, there is NOTHING that prevents that format from occuring in user supplied text in some circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of thing, parse the entries in a state-machine loop.

The following code was always the first answer to:

1. Group the HTML as specified in the question.
2. Provide click control to expand/contract the groupings.
3. Collapse entries to start -- for better initial overview.

[**See a demo of it at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Cvaw/)

### UPDATE:

The question's HTML did not match [the actual page structure](http://jsbin.com/ureyin).  Updated the script below to account for that, and also added the CSS to the script-code:

```js
var containerNode       = document.querySelector ("p font xpre");
var contentNodes        = containerNode.childNodes;
var tempContainer       = document.createElement ("div");
var groupingContainer   = null;
var hidableDiv          = null;
var bInEntry            = false;
var bPrevNodeWasBr      = false;

for (var J = 0, numKids = contentNodes.length;  J < numKids;  ++J) {
    var node            = contentNodes[J];

    //--- Is the node an entry start?
    if (    node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
        &&  bPrevNodeWasBr
        &&  /^\s*\w.*\s\(.+?\)\s+-\s+\w.+?:\s*$/.test (node.textContent)
    ) {
        //--- End the previous grouping, if any and start a new one.
        if (bInEntry) {
            groupingContainer.appendChild (hidableDiv);
            tempContainer.appendChild (groupingContainer);
        }
        else
            bInEntry        = true;

        groupingContainer   = document.createElement ("div");
        groupingContainer.className = "groupingDiv";

        /*--- Put the entry header in a special <span> to allow for
            expand/contract functionality.
        */
        var controlSpan         = document.createElement ("span");
        controlSpan.className   = "expandCollapse";
        controlSpan.textContent = node.textContent;
        groupingContainer.appendChild (controlSpan);

        //--- Since we can't style text nodes, put everythin in this sub-wrapper.
        hidableDiv          = document.createElement ("div");
    }
    else if (bInEntry) {
        //--- Put a copy of the current node to the latest grouping container.
        hidableDiv.appendChild (node.cloneNode(false) );
    }

    if (    node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE
        &&  node.nodeName === "BR"
    ) {
        bPrevNodeWasBr  = true;
    }
    else
        bPrevNodeWasBr  = false;
}

//--- Finish up the last entry, if any.
if (bInEntry) {
    groupingContainer.appendChild (hidableDiv);
    tempContainer.appendChild (groupingContainer);
}

/*--- If we have done any grouping, replace the original container contents
    with our collection of grouped nodes.
*/
if (numKids) {
    while (containerNode.hasChildNodes() ) {
        containerNode.removeChild (containerNode.firstChild);
    }

    while (tempContainer.hasChildNodes() ) {
        containerNode.appendChild (tempContainer.firstChild);
    }
}

//--- Initially collapse all sections and make the control spans clickable.
var entryGroups         = document.querySelectorAll ("div.groupingDiv span.expandCollapse");
for (var J = entryGroups.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    ExpandCollapse (entryGroups[J]);

    entryGroups[J].addEventListener ("click", ExpandCollapse, false);
}


//--- Add the CSS styles that make this work well...
addStyleSheet ( "                                                   \
    div.groupingDiv {                                               \
        border:         1px solid blue;                             \
        margin:         1ex;                                        \
        padding:        1ex;                                        \
    }                                                               \
    span.expandCollapse {                                           \
        background:     lime;                                       \
        cursor:         pointer;                                    \
    }                                                               \
    div.groupingDiv     span.expandCollapse:before {                \
        content:        '-';                                        \
        background:     white;                                      \
        font-weight:    bolder;                                     \
        font-size:      150%;                                       \
        padding:        0 1ex 0 0;                                  \
    }                                                               \
    div.groupingDiv     span.expandCollapse.collapsed:before {      \
        content:        '+';                                        \
    }                                                               \
" );


//--- Functions used...
function ExpandCollapse (eventOrNode) {
    var controlSpan;
    if (typeof eventOrNode.target == 'undefined')
        controlSpan     = eventOrNode;
    else
        controlSpan     = eventOrNode.target;

    //--- Is it currently expanded or contracted?
    var bHidden;
    if (/\bcollapsed\b/.test (controlSpan.className) ) {
        bHidden         = true;
        controlSpan.className = controlSpan.className.replace (/\s*collapsed\s*/, "");
    }
    else {
        bHidden         = false;
        controlSpan.className += " collapsed";
    }

    //--- Now expand or collapse the matching group.
    var hidableDiv      = controlSpan.parentNode.children[1];
    hidableDiv.style.display    = bHidden ? "" : "none";
}


function addStyleSheet (text) {
    var D                   = document;
    var styleNode           = D.createElement ('style');
    styleNode.type          = "text/css";
    styleNode.textContent   = text;

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    //--- Don't error check here. if DOM not available, should throw error.
    targ.appendChild (styleNode);
}
```

---

If nested/quoted entries are to be wrapped separately, you will also need to recurse.  For nested/quoted entries, open a new question after this one is answered.

Note: The new sample HTML has multiple pairs of `<html>` tags and 2 sets of entries!  This is probably a cut-and-paste error, but if it is not, open a new question if help is needed for the easy mod to process multiple sets.

Comment: Hmm when I try to run that in Chrome, I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: The code works perfectly in Chrome, I tested it before posting.  Did you try [the demo page listed](http://jsfiddle.net/6Cvaw/)?  What version of Chrome?  Post the **exact script** that gives the error and link to the target page.

Comment: I meant when I run it in Chrome's console on the actual page I need to run it on. It runs fine in jsfiddle. But if I copy that code to Chrome's console and run it on the page, I got that token ILLEGAL error.

Comment: **Link to the target page.**  If that is not possible, save the page's source to http://pastebin.com/. ... The code works from the console, or from a userscript, and I don't see a way to break it with that error.  I didn't check that `containerNode` actually exists, but that would be a different problem anyway.

Comment: Okay I got it. I was copying it from jsfiddle, which apparently is a bad idea. It pasted a bunch of extra whitespace and that caused it. Copying your code from here worked... well, it gave a valid error this time I mean: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null`

Comment: That error means that **the HTML structure given in the question does not match the page**, or the page adds it via AJAX.  You can change `document.querySelector ("body > font");` to `document.querySelector ("body font");`, but if there is more than one font tag on the page (which seems likely), you'll get unexpected results.  **Link to the target page.**  The information provided, so far, is inadequate to choose a good selector for the targeted content.

Comment: I wish I could link to it or paste the source, but it revolves around PHI and I cannot. :/

Comment: You could save the source, edit sensitive text with out changing the structure, and post that at pastebin.

Comment: Took a while (note any hard linebreaks weren't in the original, just added to read it easier), but here it is: https://gist.github.com/a0f9a5b0360a0c0c7a5d

Comment: Thanks for that, see the updated answer.  Note that the actual structure has a **crucial** difference from the question! (The `xpre` tag).  Showing the exact containing structure was also vital to designing the selector to identify the payload content.  ... ... Finally, the source you linked has multiple pairs of `<html>` tags (invalid structure) and two payload sections.  Was this a copy error?  See the updated answer.

Comment: Apparently the original page has multiple `<html>` sadly.

Comment: Open a new question for that, it's beyond the scope of how you asked this one (which by rights was answered days ago).  But the necessary change is fairly easy.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to figure out how to search the DOM to find the elements you want.  For example, you can find things by tag name and then examine the context around a given tag to see if it's what you are looking for.

If you provide more info on what exactly you're trying to find, we could likely help with more specific code.

For example, `document.getElementsByTagName("br")` finds all `<br>` tags in the document.  You could examine each one to find double `<br>` tags if that's what you're trying to find or if you're looking for some specific text before or after double `<br>`tags, you could look for that too.  As I said in my comment, you need to be more specific about what pattern you're actually looking for before more specific code can be suggeseted.

For example, here's how you would search for a particular text pattern that follows a `<br>` tag in your document:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("br");
// modify this regex to suit what you're trying to match
var re = /\w+\s\(\w+\)/;
for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    var node = items[i];
    while ((node = node.nextSibling) && node.nodeType == 3) {
        if (re.test(node.nodeValue)) {
            // add a marker test node (just for test purposes)
            var span = document.createElement("span");
            span.className = "marker";
            span.innerHTML = "X";
            node.parentNode.insertBefore(span, node.nextSibling);
        }            
    }        
}​
```

You can modify the regex to be whatever you want the search to be looking for.

You can see a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/s9VMn/

---

OK, here's one more shot at guessing what pattern you're looking for using a regular expression.  This looks for two successive `<br>` tags followed by text that matches the pattern.  It then wraps that text in a span so it can be styled according to even or odd.

```
function getTextAfter(node) {
    // collect text from successive text nodes
    var txt = "";
    while ((node = node.nextSibling) && node.nodeType == 3) {
           txt += node.nodeValue;
    }
    return(txt);    
}

function wrapTextInSpan(preNode, cls) {
    // collect successive text nodes
    // into a span tag
    var node = preNode, item;
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = cls;
    node = node.nextSibling;
    while (node && node.nodeType == 3) {
        item = node;
        node = node.nextSibling;
        span.appendChild(item);
    }
    preNode.parentNode.insertBefore(span, preNode.nextSibling);
    return(span);
}

// find double br tags
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("br");
var cnt = 1;
var re = /\w+\s+\([^)]+\)\s+-\s+(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+\d+,\s+\d+\d+/i;
for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    var node = items[i];
    // collect text from successive text nodes
    var txt = "";
    while ((node = node.nextSibling) && node.nodeType == 3) {
           txt += node.nodeValue;
    }
    // if no text, check for successive BR tags
    if (txt.replace(/\n|\s/g, "") == "") {
        if (i + 1 < len && node === items[i + 1]) {
            // found a double BR tag
            // get the text after it
            txt = getTextAfter(node);
            if (re.test(txt)) {
                wrapTextInSpan(node, "marker" + (cnt % 2 ? "Odd" : "Even"));
                ++cnt;
            }
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
​
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ewApy/

---

Here's one more version that actually inserts an expand/collapse target and does the expand/collapse of the sections.  This could be so easy with the right HTML and with a nice library like jQuery, but without either it's a lot more code:

```
function getTextAfter(node) {
    // collect text from successive text nodes
    var txt = "";
    while ((node = node.nextSibling) && node.nodeType == 3) {
           txt += node.nodeValue;
    }
    return(txt);    
}

function wrapTextInSpan(preNode, cls) {
    // collect successive text nodes
    // into a span tag
    var node = preNode, item;
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = cls;
    node = node.nextSibling;
    while (node && node.nodeType == 3) {
        item = node;
        node = node.nextSibling;
        span.appendChild(item);
    }
    preNode.parentNode.insertBefore(span, preNode.nextSibling);
    return(span);
}

function wrapBetweenInSpan(preNode, postNode, cls) {
    var node = preNode, item;
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = cls;
    node = node.nextSibling;
    if (node && node.nodeType == 1 && node.tagName == "BR") {
        preNode = node;
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
    while (node && node != postNode) {
        item = node;
        node = node.nextSibling;
        span.appendChild(item);
    }
    preNode.parentNode.insertBefore(span, preNode.nextSibling);
    return(span);
}

function toggleClass(el, cls) {
    var str = " " + el.className + " ";
    if (str.indexOf(" " + cls + " ") >= 0) {
        str = str.replace(cls, "").replace(/\s+/, " ").replace(/^\s+|\s+%/, "");
        el.className = str;
    } else {
        el.className = el.className + " " + cls;
    }
}

function hasClass(el, cls) {
    var str = " " + el.className + " ";
    return(str.indexOf(" " + cls + " ") >= 0);    
}

function addButton(target) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = "expandoButton";
    span.innerHTML = "+++";
    span.onclick = function(e) {
        var expando = this;
        do {
            expando = expando.nextSibling;
        } while (expando && !hasClass(expando, "markerContents"));
        toggleClass(expando, "notshown");
    };
    target.parentNode.insertBefore(span, target.nextSibling);
}

// find double br tags
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("br");
var cnt = 1;
var spans = [];
var re = /\w+\s+\([^)]+\)\s+-\s+(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+\d+,\s+\d+\d+/i;
for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    var node = items[i];
    // collect text from successive text nodes
    var txt = "";
    while ((node = node.nextSibling) && node.nodeType == 3) {
           txt += node.nodeValue;
    }
    // if no text, check for successive BR tags
    if (txt.replace(/\n|\s/g, "") == "") {
        if (i + 1 < len && node === items[i + 1]) {
            // found a double BR tag
            // get the text after it
            txt = getTextAfter(node);
            if (re.test(txt)) {
                var span = wrapTextInSpan(node, "marker marker" + (cnt % 2 ? "Odd" : "Even"));
                spans.push(span);
                ++cnt;
            }
            ++i;
        }
    }
}

// now wrap the contents of each marker
for (i = 0, len = spans.length; i < len; i++) {
    wrapBetweenInSpan(spans[i], spans[i+1], "markerContents shown");
    addButton(spans[i]);
}
​
```

Working demo of this version: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/cPbqC/

Comment: Yes but the data is free text, so the text1/text2 etc could also contain `<br>` (text2 does contain another `<br>`)

Comment: @JBurace - If you can't identify a pattern that you're searching for that delineates what you want to find regardless of what user content is in place, then this can't be done.  YOU have to create a pattern you're searching for and tell us what that is.  OR, show us a lot more examples of real content so we can try to figure out what a reasonable search pattern would be.

Comment: There's a pattern (each entry starts with that name/location/date). I've updated the post with more.

Comment: I ran that jsfiddle against my latest example and it put those X's after `Text1 (continued)` etc. Trying to tweak it now. EDIT: Ah it's the parenthesis; even the free text (Text1 etc) can still contain anything in it including parenthesis.

Comment: @JBurace - YOU have to tweak the regular expression to isolate only the text you want it to match from the text you don't want it to match.  You can add parts of the date to it if you want or only certain phrases for location.  You have given us INCOMPLETE information on what the allowable matches are or aren't and how to distinguish a good match from user supplied text so YOU have to figure that out by changing the regex.  For example, [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ddKer/) adds the trailing dash to the regex.

Comment: @JBurace - I added a more detailed piece of code that looks for two consecutive `<br>` tags followed by text that matches a specific regex pattern and then wraps that text in a span with a class name on it.

Comment: Ah, the clean and tidy version of my four-line hack, more like what I would've written if I could've been bothered. +1 to you. (It's only a few more lines from here to add the click-to-toggle, as per this demo where I took my original hack and made it worse: http://jsfiddle.net/C4h7s/1/.)

Comment: I added one more version that actually does the expand/collapse.  This is an example of how NOT having the appropriate HTML makes for a lot more code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of methods that let you select elements without knowing the id, e.g.:

- [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll)
- [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName)
- [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)

UPDATE: I don't see any way to distinguish between two `<br>` elements in a row that are an end-of-entry marker and two `<br>` elements in a row that are simply part of a particular entry. From your examples, the "text" entries can contain anything that might have been in the name/location/date line. So simplifying it slightly and taking *every* double-br as an end of entry you can do something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var fontTags = document.getElementsByTagName("font"),
        i, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < fontTags.length; i++)
        fontTags[i].innerHTML = '<div class="entry odd">' +
            fontTags[i].innerHTML.replace(/<br>\s*?<br>/g, function() {
            return '</div><div class="entry ' + (j++ %2===0?'even':'odd') + '">';
        }) + '</div>';
};
```

This assumes all font elements contain data to be processed and uses [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to find the double-br occurrences and put wrapper divs around each entry instead. I've given every div a class "entry", and then alternate ones the classes "even" and "odd" so that you can then apply a style like this:

```
div.odd { color : red; }
```

As shown in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C4h7s/

Obviously you could use inline styles to set the colours if you can't add classes to the stylesheet.

That's the closest I could get to your every-other-entry-is-red requirement. I'm not actually using the "entry" class for anything in that example, but at the time it seemed like it might be useful later, e.g., in this really clunky implementation of the click to toggle idea: http://jsfiddle.net/C4h7s/1/

(I don't really have time or motivation to tidy those demos up, but at least they should give you some ideas of one way to proceed. Or one way *not* to proceed, depending on how silly you think my code is.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the text contents between the `<br />`s:

1. select the `<font>` element, e.g. with [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName)
2. get its [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/childNodes) and loop over them:

   - If its [node type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType) is `1`, it would be one of your  `<br />` elements - check with [`.nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nodeName) (else you'd need to expand your loop over the elements children)
   - If its node type is `3`, it is a [text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/textnode). Get the text value and match it to your content scheme

You then should be able to build a more suitable DOM from that. You even could reuse the text nodes and just wrap them in proper tags.